# Getting this Error in Orchestrator in UiPath Exception HResult Code : -2146233088

Tags: automation, rpa, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

While trying to run the BOT from the Package deployed on the Orchestrator we are getting the below error, multiple times. But when trying to run from Uipath Studio or from the Tray we are not getting any error.

The Error as shown below

**Reason: Cannot create unknown type '{clrnamespace:Activity.ABCActivty;assembly=Activity.ABCActivty}ABCActivty'. Exception HResult Code : -2146233088**

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you running the process on the same machine you published from?

Answer (score 1):

there is difference between the studio and orchestrator packages. Try to upload the last version from Studio to Orchestrator and be sure that your Orchestrator is set properly.

Personally I in your case would remove my old settings (robots, environments, machines, etc.) and would create them again, but they could just be updated to the last version)

Also take a look here: https://forum.uipath.com/t/error-when-executing-the-automation-from-uipath-orchestrator/71721

Comment: I have already tried to put the latest package in the Orchestrator Libraries, now the frequency of getting the error has come down. But the error is coming some times. Thank You for our Reply